# update Active directory from spreadsheet

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I've created a script to read off a CSV and use 2 colums, the issue I'm getting bad output on one of the variables.

```
$users = import-csv C:\Users\admin\Desktop\ext.csv
foreach($column in $users){
set-aduser $column.user -OfficePhone "800 555 $column.ext"
}
```

The output I get in AD for the `$column.ext` is `@{ext=3512; user=jondoe}.ext`.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

You may enclose the Object.Property in a sub-expression `$()` to force the desired expansion within the quotes:

```
$users = import-csv C:\Users\admin\Desktop\ext.csv
foreach ($column in $users) {
    set-aduser $column.user -OfficePhone "800 555 $($column.ext)"
}
```

For a more detailed explanation of PowerShell's parsing modes, see [this blog post](http://rkeithhill.wordpress.com/2007/11/24/effective-powershell-item-10-understanding-powershell-parsing-modes/) from [Keith Hill](https://stackoverflow.com/users/153982/keith-hill).